# Error: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a simple Matching Algorithm. I'm quite new to programming and don't quite understand the error im getting.

The File.txt contains data in this format (without the spaces between each line):

```
5,Name,9,9,9,9

4,Name,4,8,0,3 

3,Name,4,7,3,5 

2,Name,3,5,6,3 

1,Name,5,8,2,9

0,Name,2,5,3,2
```

"A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

The error occures for "CustomNrOld = splits(0)" and I don't see why.

Would be happy about any kind of help!!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim CustomNrNew As Integer
        Dim NameIDnew As String
        Dim Alphanew As Integer
        Dim Betanew As Integer
        Dim Gammanew As Integer
        Dim Deltanew As Integer
        Dim CustomNrOld As Integer
        Dim NameIDold As String
        Dim Alphaold As Integer
        Dim Betaold As Integer
        Dim Gammaold As Integer
        Dim Deltaold As Integer
        Dim R1 As Integer
        Dim R2 As Integer
        Dim R3 As Integer
        Dim R4 As Integer

    Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Paul\\Documents\\Weever\\file.txt")
        Dim splits As String() = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
        CustomNrNew = splits(0)
        NameIDnew = splits(1)
        Alphanew = splits(2)
        Betanew = splits(3)
        Gammanew = splits(4)
        Deltanew = splits(5)
    End Using

    Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Paul\\Documents\\Weever\\file.txt")
        sr.ReadLine()
        Do While Not sr.EndOfStream
            Dim splits As String() = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
            CustomNrOld = splits(0)
            NameIDold = splits(1)
            Alphaold = splits(2)
            Betaold = splits(3)
            Gammaold = splits(4)
            Deltaold = splits(5)

            If Alphanew >= Alphaold = True Then
                R1 = (Alphaold / Alphanew) * 100
            Else
                R1 = (Alphanew / Alphaold) * 100
            End If

            If Betanew >= Betaold = True Then
                R2 = (Betaold / Betanew) * 100
            Else
                R2 = (Betanew / Betaold) * 100
            End If
            If Gammanew >= Gammaold = True Then
                R3 = (Gammaold / Gammanew) * 100
            Else
                R3 = (Gammanew / Gammaold) * 100
            End If
            If Deltanew >= Deltaold = True Then
                R4 = (Deltaold / Deltanew) * 100
            Else
                R4 = (Deltanew / Deltaold) * 100
            End If

            Dim Result As Integer
            Result = ((R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) / 4)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\Paul\\Documents\\Weever\\" & NameIDnew & ".txt",
               Result & "%" & " - " & NameIDold & " " & R1 & "% / " & R2 & "% / " & R3 & "% / " & R4 & "% " & Environment.NewLine, True)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\Paul\\Documents\\Weever\\" & NameIDold & ".txt",
               Result & "%" & " - " & NameIDnew & " " & R1 & "% / " & R2 & "% / " & R3 & "% / " & R4 & "% " & Environment.NewLine, True)
        Loop
    End Using
```

Comment: In VB.NET, you do not need to escape a backslash, so `"C:\\Users\\Paul\\Documents\\Weever\\file.txt"` would be written as `"C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Weever\file.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you are referencing something in splits() and you want it to be in an Integer variable, you'll need to convert your string to an integer (that's what the error is telling you).

For example: `CustomNrNew = splits(0)`

In this code you're trying to assign a String value (splits is an array of Strings) into an Integer (CustomNrNew). You can't convert a string directly to an integer, so you're getting an error.

To convert the string value to an integer, try using `CustomNrNew = Convert.ToInt32(splits(0))` (and replace '0' with whichever value you're using on each line).

Comment: Well the initial error is gone but now I get this error.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: On which line of your code? Check Andrew Morton's comment on your original post and make sure your file name is formatted correctly

Comment: @user2957761 That error suggests that the string you have given to Convert.Int32 cannot be parsed as a number. You should have a look at the string, even using just `MsgBox(splits(0))` just before you attempt to parse it should be enough for simple debugging.

Comment: Did all of that but a still get the second error for the CustomNrNew line. What really confuses me is that i've used the code like this before and it worked like a charm.

Comment: The Msgbox gives me a 4 which is exactly what it should be doing.

Comment: On top I just realized that all of the output files are created and contain correct data.

Comment: @PaulEtscheit An easy way to get Visual Studio to let you know about type mismatches is to use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you declared splits  as a bucket of strings

and then tried to put an string in an integer

```
CustomNrOld = Convert.ToInt32(splits(0));
```

will solve your problem